# Is it possible to collapse just one subtree without having to cycle over TAB functionality?

Tags: org-mode, subtree

What I mean is, if you have a tree, and you go to 1.2.1, I want to expand and collapse this without expanding the children (1.2.1.1 & 1.2.1.2).

In other words, normally I would have to press TAB three times, which shows the expanding of all subchildren. I just want a different key press to close the recently opened subtree.

Thanks! And hopefully I made myself clear!
EG

Answer (score 0):

Possible it is, everything is possible in emacs if you go into defining lisp functions. However that eludes my knowledge.

What I can see from the available functionality is that you can't do that in a straightforward manner. See some relevant highlights from the help for the TAB key:

```
<tab> runs the command org-cycle.

(...)

- When point is at the beginning of a headline, rotate the subtree started
  by this line through 3 different states (local cycling)
  1. FOLDED:   Only the main headline is shown.
  2. CHILDREN: The main headline and the direct children are shown.
               From this state, you can move to one of the children
               and zoom in further.
  3. SUBTREE:  Show the entire subtree, including body text.
  If there is no subtree, switch directly from CHILDREN to FOLDED.

(...)

- When there is a numeric prefix, go up to a heading with level ARG, do
  a ‘show-subtree’ and return to the previous cursor position.  If ARG
  is negative, go up that many levels.
```

Full help see `C-h k TAB'.

You can also set `VISIBILITY` properties per buffer:

```
 #+STARTUP: fold              (or ‘overview’, this is equivalent)
 #+STARTUP: nofold            (or ‘showall’, this is equivalent)
 #+STARTUP: content
 #+STARTUP: showeverything
```

see: `C-h v org-startup-folded`.

Bottom line is: maybe the easiest is to just press TAB 3 times, unless you're skilled in lisp and are willing to make the changes,,,

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. It can be used repeatedly to fold up the chain.

```
(defun my/org-fold-this-heading ()
  (interactive)
  (org-back-to-heading)
  (when (or
         ;; already folded
         (outline-invisible-p (point-at-eol))
         ;; empty subtree
         (let
             ((eoh (save-excursion (outline-end-of-heading) (point)))
              (eos (save-excursion (org-end-of-subtree t t)
                       (when (bolp) (backward-char)) (point))))
           (= eos eoh)))
    ;; move up a level before folding
    (outline-up-heading 1))
  (outline-hide-subtree))
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "M-v") 'my/org-fold-this-heading)
```